# Php slice last item in an array not working

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

```
<?php 
$current_store_type = get_field("valj_typ");
$last_type = array_slice($current_store_type, -1, 1, true);
$type_title = "";
      switch($last_type){
          case "Butik":
              $type_title = "Alla butiker";
              break;
          case "Cafe":
              $type_title = "Alla caféer";
              break;
          case "Restaurang":
              $type_title = "Alla restauranger";
              break;
          case "Service":
              $type_title = "Alla Serviceställen";
              break;
      }
?>
```

I want to slice out the last item in the  `$current_store_type` array. But it only works if the field is having **one variable**, as soon as I get it into an array it does not work.

Update: not working either

```
$current_store_type = get_field("valj_typ");
$last_type = end($current_store_type);
$type_title = "";
      switch($last_type){
          case "Butik":
              $type_title = "Alla butiker";
              break;
          case "Cafe":
              $type_title = "Alla caféer";
              break;
          case "Restaurang":
              $type_title = "Alla restauranger";
              break;
          case "Service":
              $type_title = "Alla Serviceställen";
              break;
      }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: `array_slice` gives you an array. `switch` only accept a value. You have to switch on $last_type[0] for instance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achive. It doesn't use array_slice but will function properly. If you insist on using `array_slice` check out @Random's comment in your question.

```
$last_type = end($current_store_type);
```

Comment: Hi Karl. I did that, still not working :( Updated first post with code

Comment: What is the output of the array `$current_store_type`? Use `print_r()` so we can see the content.

Comment: It prints nothing, but the function works if the get_field("valj_typ"); only passes one variable. As soon as it is more it breaks

Comment: But get_field("valj_typ") must return something. If it's only one value does it return a string or an array? Could you please post the code of that function

Comment: Actually your solution works. I had to manually go in and update all posts in wordpress for it to recache or something. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

This code did the trick for me:

```
$last_type = end($current_store_type);
```